# How to expect strings with leading '-' char in Expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I have tried this code for expecting "-bash-4.3$"

```
expect "-bash-4.3$"
```

But it does not work

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- "does not work" is the worst possible description of an error. What *does* happen? What did you want to happen?

Comment: What special characters are you talking about? And when you try the following, _how_ are you trying it? Are you typing that from a command prompt? Is it part of a script? Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You need to write `expect -- -string` otherwise expect would think `-string` is an option.

```
# expect -c 'expect -bash'
bad flag "-bash": must be -glob, [...], -timeout, -nobrace, or --
    while executing
"expect -bash"
# expect -c 'expect -- -bash'
```

Answer (score 1):

> If it says `'no such file or directory'` then you are using it wrong!

You need to define a `<testing_expect_script>.exp`

and

execute it `$ ./<testing_expect_script>.exp`

You may use following actions to have your script do something -

- expect
- send
- spawn
- interact